# Pydanic Dynamic Alias Generator Support

Tags: python, alias, pydantic

I need to support dynamic aliases in my pydantic model (if this is possible).

For this JSON data:

```
{
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2
    }
}
```

I have a pydantic class here:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
class IntraDayQuote(BaseModel):
     data: Optional[dict] = Field({}, alias='Time Series (5min)')
```

This parses correctly, BUT i want to ignore the "(5min)" part of the field name like so:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
    class IntraDayQuote(BaseModel):
         data: Optional[dict] = Field({}, alias='Time Series .*')
```

Is this achieveable with pydantic? I tried alias alias_generator from the docs but no luck:

```
def convert_field_names_for_alias(field_name):
     print(f"field name conversion: {field_name}")
     new_field_name = field_name
     if field_name.startswith("Time Series ("):
         new_field_name = "data"

     return new_field_name

 class IntraDayQuote(BaseModel):
     data: Optional[dict]
     class Config:   
          alias_generator = convert_field_names_for_alias
          allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

Comment: `{"Time Series (5min)" : {{a:1},{b:2}}}` is neither a valid Python nor JSON data structure.

Comment: Good catch. I'ved updated the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just interpose a filter function, like this:

```py
import json
import pydantic

# I've made some assumptions about the format of your data here,
# since the example you included in your question was invalid.
json_data = """
{
  "Time Series (5 min)": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
}
"""


class IntraDayQuote(pydantic.BaseModel):
    data: dict | None


def normalize_fields(d):
    return {"data" if k.startswith("Time Series (") else k: v for k, v in d.items()}


q = IntraDayQuote(**normalize_fields(json.loads(json_data)))
print(repr(q))
```

This outputs:

```
IntraDayQuote(data={'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

---

As @scolvin suggested in the comments, we could actually make `normalize_fields` a root validator, which would look like this:

```
import json
import pydantic

json_data = """
{
  "Time Series (5 min)": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
}
"""


class IntraDayQuote(pydantic.BaseModel):
    data: dict | None

    @pydantic.root_validator(pre=True)
    def normalize_fields(cls, values):
        return {
            "data" if k.startswith("Time Series (") else k: v for k, v in values.items()
        }


q = IntraDayQuote(**json.loads(json_data))
print(repr(q))
```

That's a little cleaner.

Comment: I wondered if i was using the alias generator field incorrectly or maybe misunderstood it. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: Pydantic author here, I think this is the best approach but you could move `normalize_fields` into a root validator https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators

Comment: Great! I want to learn the python/pydantic way of developing.